# 'safe' json_decode( ,,, ) to prevent exhausting memory

Tags: php, json

In my app I often call an external api that returns an json string.

```
$url = 'api.example.com/xyz';
$blah = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );
```

But in some cases I get

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in ...

I cannot control the external API, and of course I could increase the memory for php, but that has some drawbacks.

1- Whatever size I set, could still be too little.
2- If I set the memory size to 'infinite' then I could run the risk of killing my server.

Ideally I would like to 'check' before I call json_decode( ... ) that the string result into a memory exhaustion.

Is that possible?

Comment: I get the problem but IMHO this should not happen having *normal* to *medium* size responses. How large is the response in your case? (in bytes)

Comment: I agree that it should not happen, but it does happen from time to time, the response can sometime be over 32Mb, (my server limit).
As I said, the limit could/should be increased, but I would hate to increase what has so far worked very well, just for something that could go over the limit anyway.

Comment: Note that there are two separate operations above that could run you out of memory: `file_get_contents`, and separately, `json_decode`. Also, 32MB is not much memory in today's world, that seems like quite a low limit indeed.

Comment: Well in my code, the memory exhaustion is actually at the json_decode( ... ) level, the contents I get are with curl_exec( ... ).
As I said, agree with you that 32Mb is a bit low, but increasing the size could only mask the problem until the next limit is reached. I would prefer a safe way to decode, (and then I would have a safe way to get the content as well).

Comment: The point is that 32MB is ***really*** small. Use 512MB and move on to doing something more fun. :-)

Comment: Again, I agree, but making the goal posts smaller does not prevent a goal been scored. I would rather prevent a memory issue.

Comment: I'm curious @SimonGoodman, what sort of JSON data are you getting that is so bulky? For debugging, you could save your API responses to files instead of decoding them to see how large the largest of them are. And hey, if processing them isn't time-critical, but if there's data you'd rather have than not, you could then also split those saved responses into batches that fit your memory limit before decoding them. :)

Comment: I will post a url/data once the next one reaches the limit, I just need to confirm that it would not break intellectual property first.

Comment: Any luck to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem. I'm doing a while loop to get data from server, the data passed are quite small, my memory_limit has already been set to 512M,  but this won't fix the problem, after running many days, the memory exhausted. I also added some logs to write down the memory size before and after doing json_decode, from the log I can tell that sometime after running json_decode, the memory will increase 256k and never release, so many days later, it touches the memory limit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must be getting some massive JSON responses if they manage to exhaust your server's memory. Here are some metrics with a 1 MB file containing a multidimensional associated array (containing data prepared for entry into three MySQL tables with diverse data-types).

When I `include` and the file is loaded into memory as an array, my memory usage goes to 9 MB. If I get the raw data with `file_get_contents()`, it takes 1 MB memory as expected. Then, a PHP array has an approximate ratio of 1:9 to the `strlen()` of the data (originally output with `var_export()`).

When I run `json_encode()`, peak memory usage doesn't increase. (PHP allocates memory in blocks so there's often a bit of overhead, in this case enough to include the string data of the JSON; but it could bump you up one block more.) The resulting JSON data as a string takes 670 KB.

When I load the JSON data with `file_get_contents` into a string, it takes an expected 0.75 MB of memory. When I run `json_decode()` on it, it takes 7 MB of memory. I would then factor a minimum ratio of 1:10 for *JSON-data-bytesize* decoded to *native PHP array-or-object* for RAM requirement.

To run a test on your JSON data before decoding it, you could then do something like this:

```
if (strlen($my_json) * 10 > ($my_mb_memory * 1024 * 1024)) {
    die ('Decoding this would exhaust the server memory. Sorry!');
}
```

...where `$my_json` is the raw JSON response, and `$my_mb_memory` is your allocated RAM that's converted into bytes for comparison with the incoming data. (You can of course also use `intval(ini_get('memory_limit'))` to get your memory limit as an integer.)

As pointed out below, the RAM usage will also depend on your data structure. For contrast, a few more quick test cases because I'm curious myself:

- 1. If I create a uni-dimensional array with integers 1-60000, the saved PHP array size is 1 MB, but peak RAM usage is between 10.5 and 12.5 MB (curious oscillation), or a ratio of 1:12-ish.
- 2. If I create a 1 MB file's worth data as 12000 random strings as a basic associative array, memory usage is only 5 MB when loaded; ratio of 1:5.
- 3. If I create a 1 MB file's worth as a similar associative array, where half the entries are arrays as strings with a numeric index, memory usage is 7 MB, ratio 1:7.

**So your actual RAM mileage may vary a good deal.** Also be aware that if you pass that bulk of data around in circles and do a bit of this and that, your memory usage may get much (or exponentially, depending on your code economy) higher than what `json_decode()` alone will cause.

To debug memory usage, you can use `memory_get_usage()` and/or `memory_get_peak_usage()` at major intervals in your code to log or output the memory used in different parts of your code.

Comment: I get your reasoning behind that, but the values mentioned in the answer are only correct for your test data. The real memory size depends on the nature of the data. If the OP trusts that API and *really* wants to load such large responses I would advice him to simply increase `memory_limit` until it works - and has enough room for more.

Comment: @hek2mgl yes it could easily also take twice as much. Presuming the OP's API has a fairly uniform data structure, he could test for himself with the data he gets to see what sort of a conversion ratio there is. But yea, agreed, if he's using the API, he should allocate enough RAM to deal with the API. Somehow it doesn't seem right that an API should return such massive JSON chunks as to cause RAM issues, but then again, maybe he's getting ebooks or databases delivered as JSON, or something.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your code, sadly it is not a 100% fool proof method as pointed out.

Comment: @hek2mgl I crunched through a couple of quick test cases to see what sort of a range of variation we get. Of the above, by and far the largest RAM usage per array filesize was with a straight up list of integers, followed by the mixed-types data prepared for MySQL, followed by a 50/50 one-or-two-dimensional array, with a standard associative array taking the least of all. Would be curious to see a more elaborate benchmark.

Comment: You are free to be elaborated as you wish! ;) It's interesting, indeed.

Comment: @SimonGoodman it's certainly not 100%, but if you use a quantifier of 20-25 you should be on the safe side, at least as far as the four test cases above go, where the highest ratio was 1:12 as saved PHP array to RAM. The JSON equivalent to PHP's 1:X would be 0.75:X, it encodes the data a bit more byte-economically. ... Not gonna bother testing separately JSON filedata bytesizes for all these right now, you get the basic pattern and picture from the above I'm sure. :)

Comment: What I will do is set the value at 10x for now and I will post a link to a real world example that might breaks it.
I normally get a 'break' on my 32Mb limit every 2/4 hrs.

Comment: Good luck. I added a second answer about batch processing, you could also do that. N.B. there is no fool-proof way of dealing with this, because until the JSON response is decoded, there's no way of knowing what sort of a data-structure it has. It's just one long string to PHP. Unless you care to code a pre-parser that tries to estimate the likely memory usage ratio by just analyzing the data structure in the JSON string, I don't think anyone's gone down that road before. :))

Answer (score 6):

Rather than simply quit if the JSON file is too large, you can process arbitrary size JSON files by using an event-based JSON parser like https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser.  Only a small chunk of the object/array will be loaded into memory at a time.

If you have any influence over the JSON file, request or change it to be reformatted in [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format so it can be processed line-by-line with any ordinary JSON parser.

Answer (score 2):

*My first answer above is purely about avoiding the memory limit.* **Now how can you deal with the data if you hate to discard some**, but if it keeps being occasionally bulky beyond your memory limit?

Presuming that you don't need to have the response parsed in one shot and absolute real time. Then you could simply split the response into suitably sized chunks, for example with `explode()` or `preg_split()`, and save them into a temporary directory, and process later in a batch operation.

I presume the large API responses return multiple data-sets at once; if not, you could also splice a single multi-dimensional entry into more manageable chunks that are later rejoined, although that would require much more surgical precision into crafting your JSON-string splitter function.

If the multiple data-sets need to be associated in later processing (such as database-entry), you would also want to have an aggregator file containing the metadata for the batch op. (Or otherwise stick it all into a database.) You would of course have to ensure that the chunked data is well-formed. It's not ideal, but not having gigs of memory isn't ideal either. Batching is one way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need is to iterate over items in a json of unpredictable size, try [halaxa/json-machine](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine). It will never run out of memory when parsing json of any size, and uses just `foreach` to do that, no rocket science. No need to check size "safety" beforehand nor increasing php memory limit. It works like this:

```php
<?php
foreach(JsonMachine::fromFile('users.json') as $user) {
    echo $user['name'];
}
```

Comment: It works for very large json, but it is real slow. To slow for my taste.

Comment: Sure, it would be breaking the laws of thermodynamics if it wasn't slower than json_decode.