# PHP dealing with a large json string

Tags: php, json, out-of-memory

I need to communicate to a API that responses with a very large JSON response. When put into a file, the file is approximately **60MB** in size. Now when I want to `json_decode()` the response, I'm running out of memory. It is possible to set a higher memory limit and at +/- 512MB it is possible to `json_decode()` the string. But this is not the solution I want.

What is the best way approach to handle such a large response without running into memory limits.

Note: 
*I know with large CSV files, it is possible to read a file line by line. But because I need to json_decode first, I must read the whole file at once.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085943/safe-json-decode-to-prevent-exhausting-memory

Comment: I had a similar issue in my REST API. What I eventually did was bend the rules by being able to say `POST /v1/foo/bar/raw` with raw data, whereas `POST /v1/foo/bar` still accepted JSON. Then inside the API use `fopen('php://input')` to get a file handle to the large posted data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['safe' json\_decode( ,,, ) to prevent exhausting memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085943/safe-json-decode-to-prevent-exhausting-memory)

Comment: What you could also do is have a `PUT` target that takes a huge raw file, which the API would store and give a unique identifier back to the client, then reference it in a separate request when you want to process it.

Comment: @amphetamachine, The API is not in my hands, I just need to get data from the API. I cannot change the API, I just need to handle the response. At the moment I'm testing with this JSON parser, https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser, as mentioned in the possible duplicate.